# Lintian reports non-dev-pkg-with-shlib-symlink while dh_auto_install makes this link

Tags: debian, libraries, packaging

So, I am trying to build the main package of a library (which means, without the development header file).

When I run debuild lintian complains that:

```
W: libwebsitesnapshot1: non-dev-pkg-with-shlib-symlink usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwebsitesnapshot.so.1.0.0 usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwebsitesnapshot.so
```

So, I need to get rid the libwebsitesnapshot.so symlink.

Searching what debhelper does, I found out that these symlinks are being built from 2 (!) separate places. The one place was dh_link and the other one was dh_auto_configure.

In my debian/rules file I overrided dh_link with nothing, but I cannot override dh_auto_install with nothing, because it does more things than just linking.

Here's my debian/rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_auto_configure:
    dh_auto_configure -- LIB_INSTALL_DIR=/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)
override_dh_link:
```

So: How am I going to get rid of just that .so file?

What I've tried so far is adding

```
override_dh_auto_instal:
    dh_auto_install -X .so
```

to debian/rules, in an attempt to make dh_auto_install to ignore the .so symlink, but to no avail.

Comment: if you work on debian packages, you can get good answer from debian-mentors of debian mailing list.